# How do I allow a bunch of divs to automatically "linebreak"

Tags: html, css

I have a set of `div.box` objects which are in a big container `div#boxes`. Like so:

```
/-------------\
|             |
| [A] [B] [C] |
|             |
| [D] [E] [F] |
|             |
\-------------/
```

However, I want to be able to simply list the boxes A .. F and have the "linebreak" between C and D be done automatically, depending on the effective width of the outer box.

I tried different variations of `display:`. I thought a `.box {display: inline; }` should work, but due to some reason that completely eludes me, this causes all boxes to be displayed in one vertical line, even though at least two boxes should fit in one line. I also tried a combination of `div#boxes { display: table; }` and `div.box { display: table-cell; }`. Making all boxes be aligned in one horizontal line (which I kind of expected).

Currently, my boxes have all the same size and the outer box has a fixed size, but I would like to allow a more flexible layout.

Comment: If you float them or give them display:inline, don't also give them a width. If that's not the problem (i.e. they don't have explicit widths), can you make a jsfiddle or something, to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/97mmvxp2/) that shows it should just work with display:inline. Unless there are some other issues that you don't mention.

Comment: @MrLister: Thanks. The answers below appear to solve exactly my problem, I'm just contemplating which to accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [inline-block](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) value.

```
.box {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of

```
display: inline-block;
```

See my example here:

```
<style>
  .outer {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .box {
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
</div>
```